# having CORS when changing language with next-i18next library

Tags: localization, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

i'm having cors when changing language with i18n.changeLanguage function.I have two buttons that have onClick method and call a custom function named changeLang.Inside that function i am calling i18n.changeLanguage function and pass it to the lng parameter.

```
    const changeLang = lng => {
      i18n.i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    };


    <button onClick={() => changeLang('en')} className="en">
       EN
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => changeLang('tr')} className="tr">
       TR
    </button>
```

[image]

and My i18n config is just like this .

```
import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

export default new NextI18Next({
  use: [initReactI18next],
  defaultLanguage: 'tr',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['en'],
  localeSubpaths: {
    en: 'en',
  },
  localePath: '/app/static/locales',
  detection: {
    order: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
    lookupCookie: 'next-i18next',
    lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    caches: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
  },
});
```

Comment: need to be looked

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/f8a555ec5901a0a71a01b0aedc7eca2c4c7be054/src/config/default-config.ts#L6) of the lib, looks like the default `localePath` has a `public/static/locales` as a value.

**Pay Attention** that it doesn't have the first slash, try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error.Here is the correct version.I added backend object and loadPath inside it and it solved the issue.

```
import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

export default new NextI18Next({
  use: [initReactI18next],
  defaultLanguage: 'tr',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['en'],
  localeSubpaths: {
    en: 'en',
  },
  localePath: '/app/static/locales',
  detection: {
    order: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
    lookupCookie: 'next-i18next',
    lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    caches: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
  },
  backend: {
   loadPath: 'app/static/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
  }
});
```